# adjustment of values inside loop with condition in data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below.

```
code    score   
ac       2.4        
xz       2.6         
ui       3.4            
zy       1.2
```

I want to adjust score where score >2.5 and the excess score (i.e. 2.6-2.5=0.1) should be distributed to all other according to there existing score. The process should be doing this till the time every score is <=2.5.

Please help me.

output:

```
code    score    
ac       2.5             
xz       2.5           
ui       2.5                   
zy       2.1
```

Comment: can you make it more clearer? how 3.4 changed to 2.5 and how 1.2 changed to 2.1 ?

Comment: @user3280146 There is restriction of 2.5 and no score could be more than 2.5. The excess value 3.4 - 2.5=0.9 would be added to all other values that are less than 2.5 and this process would be executed till no value is > 2.5.

Comment: @user3280146 I hope it is clear now that during adjustment process the values changed.

Comment: Actually, this would not happen in any case since the input score was generated 
with a process that sum of all scores =10 and while setting values here no new is required since excess values should be assigned to all other values that are <2.5 equally.

Answer (score 1):

Did not know any pure pandas way to do that, just give a complex solution FYI.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'code': ['ac', 'xz', 'ui', 'zy'], 'score': [2.4, 2.6, 3.4, 1.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

excess = 0
def fun(it):
    global excess
    excess += it - 2.5
    return 2.5
# stage 1 handling to get total excess value
a = [i if i<=2.5 else fun(i) for i in df['score']]

def fun2(it):
    global excess
    if excess > 0:
        required = 2.5 - it
        if required <= excess:
            excess -= required
            return 2.5
        else:
            return round(it + excess, 2)
    else:
        return it
#stage 2 handling to distribute excess value to others
output = [per_a if per_a==2.5 else fun2(per_a) for per_a in a]

df['score'] = output
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  code  score
0   ac    2.5
1   xz    2.5
2   ui    2.5
3   zy    2.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Since I am very new to python and pandas I am not able to fully understand code that you have provided. It would be more helpful if you can tell me how can i do following.

psuedo Code:

while (loop till any one of score >2.5 )
        ............
       here i will update records that have >2.5 values to 2.5 
       and update excess score to all other remaning 


Please tell me only while loop syntax. I will do myself and if needed i will ask again.

Comment: You not familiar with `list comprehension`, how about `for loop syntax`?

Comment: I need while loop here, I am thinking about logic and I need while loop on score column condition. I need your help here.

Comment: You mean just change `a = [i if i<=2.5 else fun(i) for i in df['score']]` to `while syntax`, or the whole code need to be act as something like your thought which you understand?

Comment: I need code for this only : while (loop till any one of score >2.5 )

Comment: Sorry, it knocks me down to give a simple solution, my answer is really complex, let's wait for better answer together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177918/discussion-between-priya-and-atline).